# importing contacts from gmail,yahoo,msn etc from other services using java/j2ee

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, struts

I am developing a java/j2ee based web app where I am provide a feature to my web app users, where they will be able to get contacts from the different email providers like yahoo gmail and msn and many other services. Since I am building it on java, I found a open source library which is struts 1.2 based application here is the link http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/
here I have to mention that I am using Amazon web services simple emailing service to send out emails using there java api's.

I am novice or I dont knw much about the struts, I am trying to figure out how this struts1.2 based app can be integrated with my servlets or aws, sms java api.

Help me out in this regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best API is Smack API. [Click Here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/)

Comment: Why is a Jabber client library relevant here?

Comment: Yes even I want to ask the same thing. how XMPP is relevant to my requirements